# Let $S$ be the set of all integers of the form $ax + by$. Suppose that $S$ is not empty and let $d = ax_0 + by_0$ be the least element in $S$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is the rest of the question Show that every element of $S$ is divisible by $d$. 
I don’t know where to start in this problem. Here is a hint: let $n$ be an element of $S$. Then there exist integers $q$ and $r$, with $0$ less than or equal to $r$ less than $d$, such that $n = qd + r$. Using the special nature of $n$ and $d$, argue that $r = 0$.

Comment: So, $a,b$ are fixed and integers? And $x,y$ vary amongst integers?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Consider the remainder when an element of $S$ is divided by $d$

Comment: As a rule, the title should not be the beginning of the question, but a useful summary of the question. The full question should be in the body of the question.

Comment: Yes Thomas that is correct

Comment: If didn’t fit so I had to do it like that

Comment: Presumably, $S$ is the set of all positive integers of this form, or there is no such least $d.$

Comment: S has to be divisible by d